# Can i place a fixed width div next to another one that will fill the gap similar to *

Tags: css, flexbox

Using flex box can i have 2 divs in a row, one with a fixed width (say width:200px) and then the other div fill the rest of the space in a fluid way, like asterex did in Frames?

Comment: Does it have to use flex box?

Comment: Couldn't you just float it?

Comment: `div { min-width: 200px; } div + div { flex-grow: 1; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you'd do it using the flexible box model:

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    width: 500px; /* Set the available space */
}

#container > div#first {
    width: 200px;    
}

#container > div#second {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G3zeG/).

Comment: awesome thanks guys! i was actually curious about a calc solution as well! but Calc isnt as widely supported i believe

Comment: @dougmays [calc](http://caniuse.com/calc) actually seems to have better browser support than [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) does. Not by much though...

Comment: @DrydenLong yea i noticed that after i posted that comment haha.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float` and `calc` to create something like that. Here is an example:

HTML

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

CSS

```
#one {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
}
#two {
    width:calc(100% - 200px);
    height:200px;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
}
```

And a fiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/mQ2JX/

Comment: It works, but can be taxing on the browser, and not supported in older browsers.

Comment: @Chad you're right about being supported on older browsers, but I assumed that since OP is using `flex`, they don't really care about older browser support. As far as being taxing on the browser, I haven't seen any numbers to suggest that, do you have a source?

Comment: I don't have a source, but just the theory of constantly calculating a number on every resize is in theory more taxing, though maybe not always noticeable.

Comment: @Chad The browser has to convert everything to real pixel values anyway, so doing the math is probably trivial. I doubt it exhausts any more resources than doing via Javascript.